# 302 Found Document has Moved error

Tags: java, jsp, httpclient

After reading various post from stackoverflow and some help from other guys I did authentication in my code and also trying to avoid the redirect that was occuring previously as I am new to all these things. I started getting the same error back of 302 Found, document has moved.

I am trying to make a ajax call to other domain locally from my computer by writing some proxy code in jsp. And this is my jQuery AJAX code that is calling proxy.jsp page.

```
    var search_agile_metadata = 'https://search.xyz.com/ag/se/ag/get?id=';

var on_show_info = function() {
                //alert("aa");
    var outOfDomainAjaxCall = search_agile + current_doc_info.id;//An XML document
    alert(outOfDomainAjaxCall);
                request_meta_info = $.ajax({
                url: "proxy.jsp?url=" + outOfDomainAjaxCall,
                type: 'GET',
                success: on_get_metadata,
                error: on_get_metadata_agile

        });
```

And my proxy.jsp file is:-

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient,
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet,
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient,
org.apache.http.HttpResponse
,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,
java.net.HttpURLConnection,
java.net.URL,
java.util.Collection,
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient,
org.w3c.dom.*,
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder,
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory,
java.net.*,
java.io.*,
org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext,
org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams,
org.apache.http.params.HttpParams,
org.apache.http.Header,
org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParams"
contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
String a_Url = request.getParameter( "url" ) ;

URL url = new URL (a_Url);
String encoding = new String(
         org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64   
            (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8("test:test"))
          );


HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setFollowRedirects(false);
connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in   = 
    new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
   out.println(line);
}

%>

<%
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
%>
```

And when I get the response back from the server. I get this error. Any idea why I am getting this error back..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://ln.xyz.com/site/n/13000/smscc?TYPE=16777217&amp;R">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.0.58 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_jk/1.2.28 Server at search.xyz.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

That is not an error. This is an informal message. The request has just been redirected. This is a 3nn response. Only HTTP 4nn and 5nn responses are errors (4nn = client error and 5nn = server error)

Your concrete problem is that you've told `HttpURLConnection` to **not** follow redirects by the following setting:

```
connection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

So you are seeing the informal message instead of getting automatically redirected to the new request. You should rather have told it to follow redirects:

```
connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

---

**Unrelated** to the problem: please note that you are not fully utilizing the Apache HttpClient API here. You are just using the standard Java SE `URLConnection` API to make the HTTP connection. The line

```
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
```

has totally no influence on `URLConnection` behaviour. You should choose to use the one or the other. Standard `URLConnection` API *or* the Apache HttpClient.

Also please keep in mind that writing Java code in a JSP file instead of a Java class is a poor practice. You should rather be using a servlet for this job.