# how to download files from Nexus repo using java

Tags: java, file, nio, nexus, apache-commons

I need to download a file from a secure nexus repository via passing, user and password with java.

```java
URL website = new URL("http://user:password@nexus-repository/code/data/text.txt")
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(website, new File(directory), 10000, 10000);
```

**I've tried** aloft code but its downloading any random file not the actual file with actual content.

Comment: What did you mean **random file**? Did you get different files after visiting the URL every time?

Comment: It seems that your request has been redirected. Please see this: [302 Found Document has Moved error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530006/302-found-document-has-moved-error).

Comment: it returns me file with some html content.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>

Comment: File is there as i can see via logged in from browser.

Comment: Yes, because your browser handled it for you but your code not. Please see this: [How does HTTP 302 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356838/how-does-http-302-work).

Comment: Thank you. is there any way so i can handle in java code.

Comment: Try using `https` in your URL to see if it works.

Comment: its now working with https as well.