# The Document has moved - Android Studio

Tags: php, android, server, ftp

after change address from my localhost server to FTP server I get alert "The document has moved"
I made -> Build -> Clean project, but it didnt work. Do you have guys any suggestions? Thanks.

```
String login_url = "https://cui.home.pl/android/login.php";
    String register_url="https://cui.home.pl/android/register.php";
    String insert_url = "https://cui.home.pl/android/wspol_adm.php";
    String login_admin_url= "https://cui.home.pl/android/login_adm.php";
    String admin_url="https://cui.home.pl/android/admin.php";
```

Comment: where message come from?

Comment: When I oppen the app and i press "Insert" in registration form. Its the same when i want to login on Administrator panel. There is no connection.

Comment: do you check your url if its working? or 200 response?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e6654707e1b07f4a8b1f669076c289dd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530006/302-found-document-has-moved-error

Comment: Could you tell me how i can check this? I just got url server from my teacher: cui.home.pl and I transfered there php scripts in android folder so url should be: https://cui.home.pl/android/login.php
Isn't it?

Comment: i think there is problem in the server, because 302 error is a temporary redirect , ask your teacher to fix server

Comment: Thanks for help friend.